# Use Android Volley to call Python server. Why it will run two times?

Tags: java, android, python

I meet a question.
I use Android Volley to call Python server but it will call two times. How to let it run only once?

symptom : it will call the callphone.py file two times.

Android code :

url = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/callphone.py

```
private void request_z(String url) {
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    //textView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
                    requestQueue.stop();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textView.setText("That didn't work!");
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

python server code:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()


server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8080)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Server Log
Microsoft Windows [版本 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Python27>python C:\Python27\webservice2.py
xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [18/Dec/2018 09:00:20] "GET /callphone.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [18/Dec/2018 09:00:20] command: C:\Python27\python.exe -u C:\Python27\callphone.py ""
xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [18/Dec/2018 09:00:55] CGI script exited OK
xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [18/Dec/2018 09:01:00] "GET /callphone.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [18/Dec/2018 09:01:00] command: C:\Python27\python.exe -u C:\Python27\callphone.py ""
xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [18/Dec/2018 09:01:35] CGI script exited OK
```

Comment: Where are you seeing two things? Can you show your server logs?

Comment: it will dial my phone two times. I add the server log.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try Flask instead of CGI

Comment: Thanks your help~~~, I use Flask it can solve the issue.